# Why does the UI not allow you to delete a developer?

Tags: apigee

As an org admin, see the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Notice that the delete box is grayed out and unclickable.  I tried to delete via API, and that pathway works fine.  Any ideas on the discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would need to first delete the app the developer is associated to then it would allow you to delete the developer.

Comment: Thanks, Divya.  Seems this should be gated at the API level, as well. I'll recommend internally.

Comment: I also checked with Dev Portal team, and you cannot delete an Apigee Edge developer 'object' in Dev Portal, so no concerns there.